# WebGL: Is it equally safe to check all WebGL max parameters across recent browsers?

Tags: webgl

I have what I think is a basic question: Is it equally safe to check all max attributes within a user agent's GPU specs (e.g. `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, `MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`) across recent browsers?

MDN gives [one browser compatibility matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getParameter) for all of the WebGL attributes, and while I'd like to trust that matrix my instinct tells me that certain browsers will not allow users to query for all of these attributes.

Do some of the veterans around know of instances where one browser forbids javascript from accessing (or is unable to accurately report) the value of one of these WebGL attributes? Any insights others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Browser's allowing WebGL at all have to allow those to be queried otherwise you can't use WebGL correctly. Some browsers might offer a way to disable WebGL in general and I believe Firefox provides an option to make them all return the minimum required values and enforce those values so you can test your code for min spec compatibility.

Comment: @gman Thanks for your note. I can't shake the skepticism that something must be broken in IE or Edge, but if you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @gman I'm getting `invalid parameter name` in Chrome for some of the params listed on MDN, e.g. `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_ELEMENT_INDEX)` -- is there a trick to get this parameter?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had a webgl1 context, not a webgl2 context

Comment: @gman if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it